# call ajax using javascript funtion to update MYSQL result

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax

I have a table the outputs as MYSQL VALUEJAVASCRIPT TIMER

and im looking at re calling the AJAX that sends across the mysql result to update it in the table without restarting the timer.

but i get a unexpected token ) and no matter which way i write it a still get unexpected token line 56 ,I have tried changing it to }); or } and get the same all throughout and if i remove it it says its missing

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    url: 'fetch.php',
    type: 'get',
//type: 'post',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(response){
        var len = response.length;
        for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
            var beacon = response[i].beacon;
            var location = response[i].location;


            var tr_str = "<tr>" +
                "<td align='center'>" + beacon + "</td>" +
                "<td align='center'> <span class='minutes'>00</span>:<span 
class='seconds'>00</span> </td>" +
                "</tr>";

            $("#userTable tbody").append(tr_str);
        }

    }
})
});

        function updateTable() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'fetch.php',
    type: 'get',
//type: 'post',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(response){
        var len = response.length;
        for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
            var beacon = response[i].beacon;
            var location = response[i].location;


            var tr_str = "<tr>" +
                "<td align='center'>" + beacon + "</td>" +
                "</tr>";

            $("#userTable tbody").append(tr_str);
            }
    }
});
    var updateTableInterval = setInterval(updateTable, 5000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: just put the last line `(setInterval)` out of ajax brackets.

Answer (score 0):

- Your variable `updateTableInterval` is inside your AJAX option object. Moves it one line below.
- Then, your function `updateTable` is not closed, so adds a `}` at the end.
- Finally, your `$(document).ready` anonymous function is not closed either. Adds `})` at the very end.
- Do not forget to also close your `<script>` tag.

For the last three points, I said that because your code snippet have not all these. But maybe it is right on your local code.

Comment: I have updated my code based on your points but it still get the same error can you see the amended code above and let me know if i have put the updates in the correct places please?

Comment: I may have said something wrong in my answer, but now I find that the last `});` before `</script>` is not necessary. Sorry!

Comment: thank you, edited and it now loads page but doesnt seem to run the function

Comment: If you execute a `console.log` in the success of your AJAX, is it displayed?

Comment: so i have put a console.log to output 1 when the 1st ajax runs and that returns the value 1 into console log and then written 2 in the next ajax call but that never gets called